# Unit testing a function in a namespace

Tags: c++, class, unit-testing, namespaces, googletest

I'm pretty new to C++ and currently testing this production code in C++ to ramp up my skills which has:

PG.cpp

```
namespace P
{
    //other codes

    bool I::doSomething() const
    {
     return ( A.size() || B.size() );
    }

    long I::doSmthElse() const
    {
     return ( C->doSmthElse() );
    }
};
```

With the PG.h as:

```
namespace P
{
    //other codes

    class I : public ::P::J, public K
    {
    public:
      virtual bool doSomething() const;
      virtual long doSmthElse() const;
    }
};
```

I'm testing using googletest but I kept on producing an error:

```
no matching function for call to 'P::I::I()'
```

and it shows some of the candidates in the PG.h.

I believe I'm doing something wrong with calling the function especially when it involves the namespace P because it was suppose to call `P::I::doSomething()` and not the above stated in the error. Can anybody help please?

Here is my current test program:

```
#include "PG.h"

TEST( doSmthTest, test )
{
    P::I obj;
    EXPECT_TRUE( obj.doSomething() const );
}
```

Note: I'm on Linux with gcc/g++. Thank you in advance.

Edit:

If I were to directly call the function I want to test as:

```
EXPECT_TRUE( P::I::doSomething() );
```

It'll produce a new error: `cannot call member function 'bool P::I::doSomthing() const' without object`

Comment: Have you got a default constructor for class `I` in namespace `P`?  The compiler thinks not.

Comment: I'm not sure of this but In the `PG.h` the constructor is `I(type* pT, const P::Z* pZ);` @JonathanLeffler

Comment: That's a very non-default constructor, but its presence means the compiler won't generate a default constructor.  So, the compiler is correct when it complains that you're trying to use/require a default constructor but there isn't one available for use.  Either you need to add one or (more plausibly) you need revise the test so that instead of `P::I obj;` you invoke the constructor that's provided.

Comment: Ah right, now I see what you are trying to say. There isn't a constructor such as `I();` so that I can create the object from the above test. I get it now thank you. I'm still trying to figure out how to test the function. Thank you again

Comment: Yes — that's what the compiler is telling you.  I'm a little surprised it isn't complaining that the class definition doesn't include a default constructor, but I believe that's what is going on.

Comment: Thank you @JonathanLeffler !

Comment: Since the non-default constructor (which, curiously, is missing from the code in the question) takes two pointers, you could probably write `P::I obj(nullptr, nullptr);` to invoke the non-default constructor.  Now, that code might object to null pointers — though it should have considered them (it would be different if it used references instead of pointers).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've tried your suggestion on `nullptr` and it compiles successfully !! Now it's just that the gtest output fails on that specific test where it says: `unknown file: Failure, Unknown C++ exception thrown in the test body`. I guess this is good enough. I've learned something new. Thank you again Jonathan

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems to me that the constructor should probably not accept null pointers — and should throw an exception rather than successfully construct an object that can't be used.  I'm not sure if the unknown exception is coming because the code in class `P::I` consciously generates it or because it happens mostly by accident.  There may be room for improvement there.  Or it may not be worth worrying about — it depends on context, but accidentally generating the exception seems problematic to me.  You might regard the change(s) needed as 'improving the testability of the code'.